# AngularJS: display different value in select menu on select?

Tags: angularjs, json, drop-down-menu, ng-options

I have a menu that displays US States, for the user to select.  In the menu that pops up, I want to display the 2-letter state code along with the state name, but once the state is *selected* by the user I only want to display the 2-letter code.

My menu is

```
<select ng-model="ctrl.user.state" name="state" 
        ng-options="option.code + ' - '+ option.name for option in ctrl.state.options | orderBy: 'name' track by option.code" 
        class="form-control" required></select>
```

which displays the states in the format `CT - Connecticut` given my JSON data, structured as (partial):

```
{
  "name": "Connecticut",
  "code": "CT"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is close to what you want. I used one more property on the options array, and change the text on a ng-change.

http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/1433/

html

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedValue" name="state" 
        ng-options="option.code as option.code + option.nameTemplate for option in options" ng-change="changeText(selectedValue)"
        class="form-control" required></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.options = [
      {
        "name": "Connecticut",
        "nameTemplate": "- Connecticute",
        "code": "CT"
      },
            {
        "name": "Connecticut",
        "nameTemplate": "- Connecticute",
        "code": "AB"
      }
    ];


    $scope.selectedValue = "";

    $scope.changeText = function(selectedValue) {
      for(var i = 0, m = $scope.options.length; i < m; i++) {
         if($scope.options[i].code === selectedValue) {
            $scope.options[i].nameTemplate = "";
         }else {
           $scope.options[i].nameTemplate = " - " + $scope.options[i].name;
         }
      }    
    }
});
```

There is definitely something to improve on the code, but the idea is to change to text in ng-options. Let me know if you have any question :)